# It is normal rsa key fingerprint message appears when we start the cluster

Tags: hadoop, ssh

Im trying install hadoop on one node. And before start the cluster with `start-dfs.s`h and `start-yarn.sh` I generate the ssh key with `ssh-keygen` in the home folder and copy this key to authorized_keys folder with: `cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

It is normal this line below relative to rsa key fingerprint appear when we start the cluster for the first time and answer yes? Because I was seeing documentation for the installation and this message dont appears.

```
 RSA key fingerprint is 20:40:1c:2c:ab:c1:a5:25:4c:7c:93:f4:7f:bd:84.
    Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)
```

Fullmessage:

```
./start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
16/03/26 13:00:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/logs/hadoop-hdadmin-namenode-hadoop.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/logs/hadoop-hdadmin-datanode-hadoop.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 20:40:1c:2c:ab:c1:a5:25:4c:7c:93:f4:7f:bd:84.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Comment: That message is from `ssh` and not related to `hadoop` at all. If you had run `ssh-keyscan localhost,0.0.0.0 > ~/.ssh/known_hosts` prior to the first run, you won't see that message at all.